# Update Failed: There has been a critical error on your website

Tags: updates, plugin-jetpack

While updating Jetpack WordPress plugin in [Rise2Life](https://rise2life.com/) site shows error without updating the plugin. The error is:

> Update Failed: There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions. Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

I am adding the screenshot of the email that is sent by WordPress when producing the error. Please let me know what is the solution.

[image]

Comment: Need more information - it will be in the error.log file, either in the root folder of your site, or in the wp-admin folder. That will tell you what exactly caused the error. At a minimum, it may be the plugin you are updating, or another plugin interfering. You might have to disable other plugins to see if the other plugin will update. But, this type of question is best sent to the plugin's support guys, via the Support choice on the plugins' page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue and is documented on their official website for trouble shooting.

> The error may have been sent to you via an email with the subject line
>   “Your Site is Experiencing a Technical Issue”, or it may have
>   displayed in the Plugins page when you tried to update Jetpack.
>
> This happened because we moved some files around in this Jetpack
>   release, which triggers an error when they cannot be found in their
>   old locations. Your site should still have upgraded to Jetpack 8.0, so
>   refreshing the Plugins page in your dashboard should show that
>   version. The error should only happen once, on upgrade, and not after
>   that
>
> As for the frontend of the site, that should also work fine, though
>   you may want to clear any caches you have just to be sure."

if the above suits what you are experiencing and the error only appeared once during update or after update and the version is up to date and now working fine. then you can ignore anything below, it's normal.

If you refresh the plugins page and it is still showing the old version OR the site has errors on it still. I would suggest manually downloading the latest plugin zip and re-uploading it into your plugins directory overriding the old files. Dont forget to backup your database AND the old plugin folder first. That should solve your issue if the original statement did not apply to you.