# There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.Learn more about debugging in WordPress

Tags: plugins

my cpanel is online file manager. in all video tutorial i watched their file manager only. and i tried to do what they do but it douesnt work to my website

Comment: You'll need to talk to your hosting provider about this.

Comment: Please see comment here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354064/update-failed-there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website . But, if you are unsure of what/how to do, contacting your hosting provider support is best idea.